# Add EditText to Toolbar

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view, toolbar

My `Toolbar` and `EditText` look like this:

[image]

I tried adding it as an `ActionView` but I got this result:

[image]

It basically just added my words 'Tap Below' as a title without the `TextView`

Here's what I did:

menu.xml

```
<menu>
    ... 
    ...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_menu"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="Tap Below"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/edit_text_layout"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        />
</menu>
```

edit_text_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:background="#000000">

</EditText>
```

I thought by doing this I add my `EditText` layout to the `Toolbar`...
Can someone please help?

Alternatively, is there a trick where I can overlay the `EditText` on the `Toolbar`?

I tried adding `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Just add the `EditText` to the XML for your `ToolBar`. That is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Works great! But how come it doesn't add it as an menu item through my code?

Comment: The menu is for the "Options Menu". It is different. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just add the `EditText` to the XML for your `ToolBar`. That is probably the easiest way.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
      <EditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/myEditText"
         android:background="#000000" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: @JaredBurrows i don't have menu option with that solution

Answer (score 6):

1. Add the EditText to the Toolbar xml.
2. Add the `Toolbar` to your `Activity's` xml layout, at the top.
3. Set the toolbar as ActionBar:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   }
   ```

This will make the toolbar "become" the `ActionBar` with `EditText` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Use belove code

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="June 14"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_daily" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```